# Using a gaming keyboard on OSX

Tags: macos, drivers, keyboard

I am trying to use a Gaming Keyboard from Armageddon on OSX. It works well on Windows but on both linux and OSX the modifier keys are badly off.. Anyone have any experience hacking this?

Full question at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204945/trouble-using-a-gaming-keyboard-on-osx

Sorry for the double post. Not sure which is the right place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about doing is keyboard mapping.  You want to adjust the way the keyboard sends input to the OS.  The map has expected characters/functions, and you identify the matching key.  I am providing a link that will assist you in this endeavor.  I am leaving a link because they bring up a valid point.  What you are attempting to do can leave you needing to reinstall if you mess it up.  This isn't a simple go here, change x to y and voila...

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20010508131542947

In OSX you will have to change the mappings every time you upgrade your OS.  This may be true in Linux depending on flavor, packages, versions, configuration...

Comment: Interesting, Ill take a look. The difficult part is that it isnt that the keys are messed up, that I could probably fix with KeyRemap4Macbook. But the keys in question dont, for all intents and purposes, work at all on mac.. So it is an odd question. Ill take a look and report back

Comment: That was some relevant and useful information... Now what you may run into is that the Mac doesn't have a starting point in the map.  So you would have to figure out what to put in the map, then tell it what the key is on the keyboard.  You have to have a method of explaining to the OS what the key you are pressing is supposed to do.

Comment: Most of the links are dead on that article :(

Comment: The article was more meant to make it clear that what you need is a driver.  This is no small order and is easily outside the scope of what you could get here.  You may want to try hiring a freelancer to code one up for you.  I would be wary of anything free that I was offered because you would have to install it at the kernel level.  That opens you up to potential attacks.

Comment: Thats too much effort for me :( I am just trying to make the best of a bad purchase here..

Comment: If i wanted to write and replace the driver for this particular keyboard.. is that possible? Do you have any place for reference into this? I wonder if it is possible there is a OSS driver code out there that I can mod and use.. sounds like a fun proj..